# Issue with opacity option in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, transparency

The following

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newtcbox{\mytransparentbox}{blank, on line, opacitytext=0.4}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}
\mytransparentbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image].

The used pdf file is available [here](https://github.com/colasbd/bug_opacity_tcolorbox).

I would like the inside of the wheel to be white (or fully transparent). Is there any fix?

---

PS: The package `transparent` does not work in my case (because of package conflict I guess), so I'm looking for a solution not using it.

---

PPS: I am looking for a solution that does not require to modify the images (for instance to convert it to a `png` image).

Comment: Does your PPS exclude solutions that fix the problems in the pdf but still has the image as pdf?

Comment: Not necessarily. I have created the pdf with [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of Ulrike's code to include the white rectangle in tcbox options. It's possible to include graphics commands after the text with `finish` option (section 10.9, page 197).

```
\newtcbox{\mytransparentbox}{blank, on line, 
      finish={\fill[white, opacity=0.6] (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);}}
```

And another option could be to apply similar options to a `\tcbincludegraphics` box. This command (section 11.1, page 251) puts an image included by `\includegraphics` command inside a `tcolorbox`. In this case

```
\tcbincludegraphics[...]{engine}
```

The complete code with both examples is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Original command with `finish` option
\newtcbox{\mytransparentbox}{blank, on line, finish={\fill[white, opacity=0.6] (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);}}

%Options for tcbincludegraphics
\tcbset{
    mytransparentbox/.style={
        blank, hbox, on line, 
        graphics options={scale=0.1},       
        finish={\fill[white, opacity=.6]
            (frame.south west) rectangle 
            (frame.north east);}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}
\begin{tikzpicture}%%%%%% Ulrike's solution
\node[inner sep=0pt] (a){\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}};
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.6}
\fill[white](a.south west)rectangle (a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\mytransparentbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}}
\tcbincludegraphics[mytransparentbox]{engine}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could place a white rectangle with an opacity over the picture:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtcbox{\mytransparentbox}{blank, on line, opacitytext=0.4}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (a){\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}};
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.6}\fill[white](a.south west)rectangle (a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\mytransparentbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First convert the **PDF** file into a **PNG** image and then apply the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newtcbox{\mytransparentbox}{blank, on line, opacitytext=0.4}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine1}
\mytransparentbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{engine1}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot convert the pdf file to png...

Comment: @Colas Use this online converter https://pdf2png.com/

Comment: @Colas Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Not really, I am looking for an answer that does not require to modify the image.

Comment: I think a PDF has not a background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81340/discussion-between-cragfelt-and-colas).

Answer (score 1):

A non-latex approach:

The syntax of the pdf file looks a bit strange. Instead of including the shapes directly, it includes larger squares which are clipped to form the gears.

The problem with the transparency can be circumvented if the inner circle is filled in white, which can be done by editing the pdf in e.g. inkscape.

I uploaded the fixed version of the pdf to https://github.com/colasbd/bug_opacity_tcolorbox/blob/6893ed5d0222596010310882a17986fb63ce19ae/engine_fix.pdf

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have created the PDF in [sketch](http://www.sketchapp.com)